# Golf Problem Math

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

Hey guys i cant seem to draw the diagram for this. I dont understand this question at all. I got this triangle but i dont know how to solve it. I only have 2 sides on it and i cant use the sin/cos law to solve it... Please help

A famous golfer tees off on a straight 400 yard par 4 and slices his drive to the right. The drive goes 290 yards from the tee. Using a 7 iron on his second shot, he hits the ball 170 yards and it lands inches from the hole. How many degrees to the right of the line from the tee to the hold did he slice the drive?

As i said i got a triangle but only two sides on it. Please help Thankyou.

Comment: You have three sides, the 400 straight shot, the 290 drive, and the 170 second shot.

Comment: I think you have all three sides of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You have three sides.  The third side is the $400$ yard length of the hole.  Now use the law of cosines to get the angle.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot i understand now!